# How touchdown and touchup events work-LibGdx

Tags: events, libgdx, touch

I have two events to be performed on same object.One in touch and other on releasing/removing that touch.
I hope I can do this with touchup and touchdown events using Inputprocessor.

Something I have tried.

```
if (MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown) {

        stickSprite.setSize(stickSprite.getWidth(), stickSprite.getHeight()    + 500.0f);
        } 

       if (MyInputProcessor.isTouchUp)
        {
             if(anglevalue>=0)
                {
                    anglevalue++;
                stickSprite.setRotation(70f);

                }
        }
```

Here if clause for touch up is not executing.

How this events actually work?

How can I use this events effectively to fulfil my requirement?

Comment: Show your MyInputProcessor. Also, what s `angleValue` for? Do you realize you're incrementing it by one on every frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like, you want to increase size of an image in height wise when user touch the screen and increase until he remove his finger from screen and then rotate that image by 90 degree.

I tried this, Hopefully it may be give you some reference

```
public class TestGame extends Game implements InputProcessor{

Texture pixelTex;

SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite sprite;
float w,h;

TouchStatus touchStatus=TouchStatus.NONE;

enum TouchStatus {
    TOUCH_DOWN,TOUCH_UP,NONE
}

@Override
public void create() {

    w=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    h=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
    pixelTex= getPixmapTexture(Color.WHITE);

    sprite=new Sprite(pixelTex);
    sprite.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    sprite.setSize(10,10);
    sprite.setPosition(200,200);
}

@Override
public void render() {
    super.render();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();

    if(touchStatus==TouchStatus.TOUCH_DOWN){

        if(sprite.getY()+sprite.getHeight()<h){
            float currentHeight=sprite.getHeight();
            currentHeight++;
            sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth(),currentHeight);
        }
    }
    if(touchStatus==TouchStatus.TOUCH_UP){
        float currentRotation=sprite.getRotation();
        currentRotation--;
        sprite.setRotation(currentRotation);
        if(currentRotation<=-90)
            touchStatus=TouchStatus.NONE;
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    super.resize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pixelTex.dispose();
    spriteBatch.dispose();
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    if(touchStatus==TouchStatus.NONE)
    touchStatus=TouchStatus.TOUCH_DOWN;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if(touchStatus==TouchStatus.TOUCH_DOWN)
    touchStatus=TouchStatus.TOUCH_UP;
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
  }

public static Texture getPixmapTexture(Color color){
        return new Texture(getPixmapRectangle(1, 1, color));
}

public static Pixmap getPixmapRectangle(int width, int height, Color color){
        Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(color);
        pixmap.fillRectangle(0,0, pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight());

        return pixmap;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Hey!Thank you!! I run this code and it looks like what I am trying to do for days.I was trying different ways to implement this type of logic and getting a very hard time on this.I hope using this code ,I can implement the logic that I want!Thanks again!